# Hello trying to make a post http request during login . how do I access a value inside a map that contain string values

Tags: flutter

```
List userData = [];
Future<APIResponse<bool>> loginUser(LoginUser item) {
var url = '$API/login';
print('url is: $url');
return http
    .post(url, headers: headers, body: json.encode(item.toJson()))
    .then((data) {
  if (data.statusCode == 201) {
    print("data contains: ${data.body}");
    userData.add(data.body);
    print(userData[0]["id"]);

    return APIResponse<bool>(data: true);
  }
  if (data != null) {}
  return APIResponse<bool>(
      error: true, errorMessage: 'Eustero An error occured');
}).catchError((e) {
  print('error is: $e');
  APIResponse<bool>(error: true, errorMessage: 'MWai An error occured');
});
```

}

this is

```
data.body
```

'''data contains: {
"id": 29,
"token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpZCI6MjksImV4cCI6MTYxNjQ0MjE1M30.bdMVxI_1QEZDx9psCPloheeDzYRgKpirGvDoGyuEqqc"
}'''

When I try to get the id I get the error error is: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'.

Comment: You say "when I try to get the id" - can you post the code you're using the get the id? As written, your code compiles and works without throwing any errors ([repl](https://repl.it/@superhawk610/AbleLiquidIntranet)).

Answer (score 0):

you are getting a single object as a response but you are trying to access a value from a list of objects.

to access the value try:

```
print(data["id"]);
```

Comment: when I print data["id"], I get the error The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Response from the Ide

Comment: sorry I missed a point in my answer. you can use Map instead of List for userData then try to access the value by its key. 

try this:

`Map userData;`
....
....
`userData = jsonDecode(data.body);`
`print(userData["id"]);`

Comment: Thank you when using a Map then decoding 'data.body' it works fine Thank You

Answer (score 0):

As I can see your `Id` in map is of type int. You are allowed to print out String representation of an object, so cast `toString()` here:

```dart
print(userData[0]["id"].toString());
```